# Why can't I customize classes for an element that is disabled in Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, button, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI for styling components, but I cannot customize the label class when the button is disabled. I'm setting a reference "&$disabled" but it does not help me.

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

// The `withStyles()` higher-order component is injecting a `classes`
// prop that is used by the `Button` component.
const StyledButton = withStyles({
  root: {
    background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
    borderRadius: 3,
    border: 0,
    color: "white",
    height: 48,
    padding: "0 30px",
    boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)"
  },
  label: {
    "&$disabled": { backgroundColor: "blue", textTransform: "capitalize" }
  },
  disabled: {}
})(Button);

export default function ClassesShorthand() {
  return <StyledButton disabled>classes shorthand</StyledButton>;
}
```

Here is a link on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7s9u3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate issues:

1. You put your `&$disabled` reference within the `label` class, but the `label` class is applied to a `span` within the button whereas the `disabled` class is placed on the button itself, so the resulting CSS with `.MuiButton-label.Mui-disabled` won't match anything. You can fix this by moving `&$disabled` under `root` instead of `label`.
2. The other issue is that in `root` you are specifying a `background-image` property via the `linear-gradient`, but you are only overriding `background-color` and the background color isn't shown when a background image is present, so for the disabled case you need to remove the background image.

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

// The `withStyles()` higher-order component is injecting a `classes`
// prop that is used by the `Button` component.
const StyledButton = withStyles({
  root: {
    background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
    borderRadius: 3,
    border: 0,
    color: "white",
    height: 48,
    padding: "0 30px",
    boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
    "&$disabled": {
      backgroundImage: "none",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      color: "rgba(255,255,255,0.6)",
      textTransform: "capitalize"
    }
  },
  disabled: {}
})(Button);

export default function ClassesShorthand() {
  return <StyledButton disabled>classes shorthand</StyledButton>;
}
```

[image: Edit disabled button background]

---

If you are intentionally wanting to target the span within the button rather than the button itself, you can do the following (which targets the `label` class as a descendant of the `disabled` class):

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

// The `withStyles()` higher-order component is injecting a `classes`
// prop that is used by the `Button` component.
const StyledButton = withStyles({
  root: {
    background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
    borderRadius: 3,
    border: 0,
    color: "white",
    height: 48,
    padding: "0 30px",
    boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)"
  },
  label: {
    "$disabled &": {
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      color: "rgba(255,255,255,0.6)",
      textTransform: "capitalize"
    }
  },
  disabled: {}
})(Button);

export default function ClassesShorthand() {
  return <StyledButton disabled>classes shorthand</StyledButton>;
}
```

[image: Edit disabled button background on label]

Answer (score 0):

Material-ui Button has `disabled` css rule, and you gave it empty object. 
The following works:

```
const StyledButton = withStyles({
  root: {
    background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
    borderRadius: 3,
    border: 0,
    color: "white",
    height: 48,
    padding: "0 30px",
    boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)"
  },
  disabled: { background: "blue", textTransform: "capitalize" }
})(Button);
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Comment: In your sandbox, the blue background color is not being displayed (the linear-gradient is still being displayed instead).

Comment: @RyanCogswell You are right, thank you. I fixed it by overriding the background property.